# GTK: g_timeout_add() Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gtk3

The following code executes perfectly on almost the linux platforms I've tested (Ubuntu, Mint, Raspbian x86) but fails completely on Raspbian for Raspberry Pi.

It successfully executes randomly a handful of times then stops triggering. The remainder of the program executes fine including several other timeouts added in the exact same manner and nothing else suffers in any noticeable manner.

Could it be the 5ms timeout that the raspberry pi can't keep up to? Why is it only that one aspect that fails while all other aspects display no glitches etc. Its as if the timeout is being cancelled for some reason or another.

```
void control_init() {

...

  g_timeout_add(20, control_quick_timer_event, NULL);

...

}



void control_quick_timer_event() {

  control_read_values();

  control_since_last++;

  if (control_since_last == 2) {

    while (serialDataAvail(control_serial)) {

      serialGetchar(control_serial);

    }

    control_read_state = -1;
  }
}
```

*** Edit ***
The additional of a printf("\n"); "fixes" the issue for an unknown reason but I can't accept it as a solution as I need the serial print out without millions of spaces.

return True;/return 1; at the tail also result in the same error, this has no impact on the result.

Comment: The addition of printf("\n"); at the end of control_quick_timer_event()  is sufficient to maintain the cycle? This has been a recurrent issue with GTK requiring these useless print new line commands at obscure locations. What is going on?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you have now is not verifiable, and probably the bug is in the rest of the code and not in the code you posted. This code is almost definite to not work according to the Gtk3 documentation.

Comment: As an anecdote: I also have found that sometimes originally presented code works. It has been working for like 10 years on Debian Squeeze. Then I migrated the code to upgraded system and all those places started to explode. That's how I found out that g_timeout callbacks need to have specific definition (I inherited this code). Your original code does not compile on my machine `no known conversion from 'void ()' to 'GSourceFunc' (aka 'int (*)(void *)') for 2nd argument`. And the places with the printf fix? For three days I have been debugging stack corruptions until I got to the bottom of it;)

Comment: If you were having error messages, you should have posted those too. We can't see what you are seeing. If you don't post all the errors you have, we can't help you, and then your StackOverflow account will be closed. Please edit your question with the error you have in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because your handler returns void. From [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.56/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add):

> The function is called repeatedly until it returns FALSE, at which
>   point the timeout is automatically destroyed and the function will not
>   be called again.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean control_quick_timer_event(gpointer data)
{
    printf("I'm still alive\n");
    return TRUE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    g_timeout_add(20, control_quick_timer_event, NULL);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the comment I added to the original question, how does the added line therefore rectify the issue?

Comment: You are passing function that returns `void` where it expects `bool`. Compiler let's it pass probably because callbacks in gtk are cast to `void*` (if I remember correctly), but it still is an undefined behaviour. `printf` helps rather as a coincidence of undefined behaviuor than a fix. I'll add some working code.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @pan-mroku is trying to tell you, you need this code:

```
bool control_quick_timer_event() {

  control_read_values();

  control_since_last++;

  if (control_since_last == 2) {

    while (serialDataAvail(control_serial)) {

      serialGetchar(control_serial);

    }

    control_read_state = -1;
  }
return True;
}
```

If you don't `return True`, the timeout will be canceled.

Comment: This solution doesn't work I'm afraid, it makes no difference if the return true is present or not. Note also that the code works as originally presented on any other platform so it's odd that that would be the reason why it fails in this instance.

Comment: Also change `void` to `bool`.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, I usually code in Python, and that works a bit different.